# dynamic (scalar) cast in php

Tags: php, casting

I need to cast value in type define in string.
For the moment i use this:

```
/**
 * @param mixed $val
 * @param string $type
 *
 * @return bool|float|int|string
 */
protected function castTo($val, $type)
{
    switch ($type) {
        case 'boolean':
        case 'bool':
            return (boolean) $val;
        case 'integer':
        case 'int':
            return (int) $val;
        case 'string':
            return (string) $val;
        case 'double':
        case 'float':
            return (float) $val;
        default:
            return $val;
    }
}
```

But do you know a better solution ( in php 5.6 and 7+ ) ?

Comment: This sounds like a [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). The easy way is just to inline your casts, since you literally are doing that in a switch case.

Comment: yes, but HOW ? you can't ($type) $var ;

Comment: But you literally do that here..? What do you think `castTo(20, 'boolean')` resolves to? --> `return (boolean) 20`

Comment: Ho i understand, i didn't like the written code ...i search a 'one line' solution...

Comment: Just replace every call of `castTo()` with an inline cast..? I really don't see what the issue is here, sorry...

Comment: @Loek is right. The way you are trying to go about this is actually more work. Your way: `$myBool = castTo('1', 'boolean');` = 33 keystrokes. Inline way: `$myBool = (boolean)'1';` = 23 keystrokes. It is perfectly OK to cast inline in your code. In fact, it is a necessary part of programming and not really something that needs to be factored out into a separate space. Sounds like you're trying to solve a problem that doesn't need a solution. What exactly is the *problem* you're trying to solve?

Comment: i try to compare 2 value but php seem to fail 
https://ibb.co/f2TCiJ ( 1 first dump var1 hardcoded for testing, other var come far away from the reste of the code )

Answer (score 1):

Use the function equivalents like [`intval`](http://php.net/intval) to get a "dynamic handle":

```
$funcs = ['boolean' => 'boolval', 'integer' => 'intval', 'string' => 'strval', 'float' => 'floatval', ...];

if (!array_key_exists($type, $funcs)) {
    return $val;
} else {
    return call_user_func($funcs[$type], $val);
}
```

Note that this may be shorter, but not necessarily overall *better* than a `switch`…

Answer (score 0):

like @deceze solution ... but directly in phplib
http://php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php